# Why exciton-plasmon electromagnetic coupling is possible?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, plasmon, photonics

There is a number of works about exciton-plasmon hybrid excitations (polaritons) in nanostructures, for example:

https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4895061?journalCode=jap

https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/nanoph.2018.7.issue-1/nanoph-2017-0059/nanoph-2017-0059.xml

In these papers, exciton and plasmon are assumed to couple via electromagnetic field. However it is known that:

1) any configuration of electric field can be decomposed into longitudinal and transverse fields ([Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition));

2) plasmons interact only with the longitudinal electric field (density response), while excitons interact only with the transverse field.

**So how excitons and plasmons couple to each other electromagnetically?**